# How do I install specific icu4c version via homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, icu4c

`brew install icu4c` gives me 73.2, how do I trick homebrew to install icu4c 71.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Find **icu4c.rb** in

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/i/icu4c.rb`

or in

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/icu4c.rb`

Edit lines 4,5,6 with this:

- url "https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-71-1/icu4c-71_1-src.tgz"
- version "71.1"
- sha256 "67a7e6e51f61faf1306b6935333e13b2c48abd8da6d2f46ce6adca24b1e21ebf"

Then perform `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1` and `brew install icu4c`

Comment: It gives the following error:
Error: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/71.1 is not a directory